# How JS files are available in browser in dev tools when bundler have merged them into one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, browser

How JS files are available in browser in dev tools when bundler have merged them into one. I read that webpack uses bundler to merge all imported files into one , which comes as bundle.js i brower but still we have JS files also available when we debug them in browser. My question is how browser is able to give us debug functionality when it is using bundle.js

I tried https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html to understand things but did not got far enough

Comment: At some level, it has to be plain, ordinary Javascript.  The browser doesn't understand anything else.

Comment: but then why bundling is done if browser is using plain javascript files

Comment: To reduce the number and size of web transfers.  If the browser can fetch 12 Javascript files through one request, that's a huge time savings.  The network is SLOW compared to the processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most bundlers don't *only* generate bundles of JavaScript code from many source files, they also typically produce additional files known as **source maps**. These source maps live alongside the bundled files, and provide instructions to software like a web browser about how the bundled files relate to the source files that were used to produce them.

By using these source maps, your web browser is able to show you the source files in its dev tools, even though the actual files that are being run on the page might be a bundle. These source maps also let you interact with these bundles as though you were interacting with the source files, for example by adding breakpoints for debugging.

Typically, bundlers will provide a range of options for generating different types of source maps with different benefits and downsides, and it's common for automated build systems to use different rules for generating source maps in different environments.

For example, some types of source maps are fast to generate, but the files are very large. This makes them suitable for local development, where source files change often as you develop, but less useful for deploying to a production environment. Not every project will deploy any source maps to production at all.

You mentioned Webpack in your question. Here's a link to the documentation for how Webpack lets you configure how it generates source maps via its `devtool` configuration option: [Devtool | webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)

Different bundlers have different options for generating sourcemaps. Here's the documentation for a different bundling tool, esbuild: [Sourcemap | esbuild - API](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#sourcefile)